# python - How to format variable number of arguments into a string?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

We know that formatting **one** argument can be done using **one** `%s` in a string:

```
>>> "Hello %s" % "world"
'Hello world'
```

for two arguments, we can use two `%s` (duh!):

```
>>> "Hello %s, %s" % ("John", "Joe")
'Hello John, Joe'
```

So, how can I format a variable number of arguments *without having to explicitly define within the base string a number of `%s` equal to the number of arguments to format*? it would be very cool if something like this exists:

```
>>> "Hello <cool_operator_here>" % ("John", "Joe", "Mary")
Hello JohnJoeMary
>>> "Hello <cool_operator_here>" % ("John", "Joe", "Mary", "Rick", "Sophie")
Hello JohnJoeMaryRickSophie
```

Is this even possible or the only thing I could do about it is to do something like:

```
>>> my_args = ["John", "Joe", "Mary"]
>>> my_str = "Hello " + ("".join(["%s"] * len(my_args)))
>>> my_str % tuple(my_args)
"Hello JohnJoeMary"
```

NOTE: I **need** to do it with the `%s` string formatting operator.

**UPDATE**:

It needs to be with the `%s` because a function from another library formats my string using that operator given that I pass the unformatted string and the args to format it, but it makes some checking and corrections (if needed) on the args before actually making the formatting.

So I need to call it:

```
>>> function_in_library("Hello <cool_operator_here>", ["John", "Joe", "Mary"])
"Hello JohnJoeMary"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you *need* to use the `%s` operator? That makes little sense; use `str()` instead.

Comment: How would the "cool operator here" specify how to connect up the values? You don't want it to just print out `Hello JohnJoeMary`, or  `Hello ("John", "Joe", "Mary")`, do you? You might want `Hello John, Joe, Mary` or `Hello John, Joe, and Mary` or `Hello John, Joe and Mary`, or a million other things; there's no way a single operator could let you do all of those.

Comment: You should still be able to call it with `function_in_library("Hello %s", ', '.join(["John", "Joe", "Mary"])`

Comment: Sorry, I explained the library function wrong. Anyway, I may **not** `join` the arguments before passing them to the function :\

Comment: I suppose f-strings are now the best way to handle this, since they allow for function evaluation in the string literal

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'd use `str.join()` on the list *without* string formatting, then interpolate the *result*:

```
"Hello %s" % ', '.join(my_args)
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_args = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> "Hello %s" % ', '.join(my_args)
'Hello foo, bar, baz'
```

If some of your arguments are not yet strings, use a list comprehension:

```
>>> my_args = ["foo", "bar", 42]
>>> "Hello %s" % ', '.join([str(e) for e in my_args])
'Hello foo, bar, 42'
```

or use `map(str, ...)`:

```
>>> "Hello %s" % ', '.join(map(str, my_args))
'Hello foo, bar, 42'
```

You'd do the same with your function:

```
function_in_library("Hello %s", ', '.join(my_args))
```

If you are limited by a (rather arbitrary) restriction that you cannot use a `join` in the interpolation argument list, use a `join` to create the formatting string instead:

```
function_in_library("Hello %s" % ', '.join(['%s'] * len(my_args)), my_args)
```

Comment: Though you are right, I think I didn't explain my question clear enough. I missed to state that I'm not making the formatting, an existing function is. Sorry, but thanks. I'll update my question.

Comment: Sorry I may not `join` the arguments, each one needs to be processed by the library function before formatting. Thanks.

Comment: That is a rather arbitrary restriction; in that case build the `%s` string elements using a separate join: `"Hello %s" % ', '.join(['%s'] * len(my_args))`. Note the irony here; you are creating the string using the *exact same technique*.

Comment: Yeah, I use that example in my question, but I say I'd rather not to do so *if there was* another way around. Basically my question is **if a somehow-magic operator even exists** or I if **must** build the string myself? But I guess the second is the answer I'm getting :/
Sorry if this sounds rude, I don't mean to.

Comment: You *must* build the string yourself.

Comment: The last example is exactly what I needed to incorporate 'and' and 'or' before the last arg. Thanks!