# writing arrays and strings to file using '%' operator

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to export data in a certain format (.cube file); the file type isn't the main issue.

Now I have to print different line formats based on their line number. So far so good, I'm able to do it using the following:

```
 if line_num == 0 or line_num == 1:
     # comment line
     output_file.write("%s\n" % (self.comments[line_num]))
     continue
 if line_num == 2:
     # number of total atoms, and the origin coordinates
     output_file.write("%4d %.6f %.6f %.6f\n" % (self.num_atoms, self.origin[0], self.origin[1], self.origin[2]))
     continue
```

The above work, but I've wanted to use the '%' operator in the following manner:

```
if line_num == 2:
     # number of total atoms, and the origin coordinates
     output_file.write("%4d %.6f %.6f %.6f\n" % (self.num_atoms, self.origin)
```

because `self.origin` is a `Numpy` Array size 1X3.

When doing so, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

is there a way to do what I wanted instead of give every element in the array.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `*self.origin`

Comment: In addition to @Barmar advise - get using new-style string formatting or f-strings in 3.6+ https://pyformat.info/

Comment: @buran How would he do this with f-strings? Wouldn't that require him to write `{self.origin[0]} {self.origin[1]} {self.origin[2]}`, which is what he's trying to simplify?

Comment: yes, in this particular case it would be better to use str.format() method and star-unpack `self.origins`. On other hand - they still has to have format placeholders for every element of `self.origin`. It may be better to convert `self.origins` to str beforehand and have just two format placeholders. My advise was more general - to move away from old-style string formatting, more over they use python 3

Comment: Using iterable unpacking (`*self.origin`) works in Python 3, but not in Python 2.
In Python 2, you actually have no choice but to write out the entire thing (`self.origin[0], self.origin[1], self.origin[2]`).

Comment: `np.txtsave` iterates on the rows of an array, and formats with `fmt%tuple(row)`, where `fmt` has as many `%` terms as there are elements the (first) row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `self.origin` is a list, and you are trying to print a list using float formatting, you can unpack the list using `*self.origin` and then it should work, see a simple example below.

You can use `string.format` which works for for both `python2` and `python3`

```
origin = [1,2,3]
print("{:4d} {:6f} {:6f} {:6f}".format(1, *origin)) 
#   1 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
```

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:17:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> origin = [1,2,3]
>>> print("{:4d} {:6f} {:6f} {:6f}".format(1, *origin)) 
   1 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
```

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:39:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> origin = [1,2,3]
>>> print("{:4d} {:6f} {:6f} {:6f}".format(1, *origin))
   1 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
```

Comment: Updated @1313e please check! and consider upvoting if it works

Comment: Yes, using `format` will work, as iterable unpacking inside a function call works in Python 2. Keep in mind that in Python 2, `.format(*origin, 1)` will not work as only named arguments are allowed to follow an iterable unpacking in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for the help! would appreciate some votes also

Answer (score 4):

Use `*self.origin` to unroll the array.

```
>>> "%4d %.6f %.6f %.6f\n" % (num_atoms, *origin)
' 199 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000\n'
>>>
```

Comment: Ive tried but I get the following:
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
might it be python3 issue?

Comment: noted! is there away that works for both py2 and py3?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391059/python-how-to-format-variable-number-of-arguments-into-a-string

Comment: Hi @EE_student_TAU, check my answer below, should work for  both python2 and python3

Comment: @EE_student_TAU it's alright if you wanna have have something be backwards compatible but for new code there's no reason to target python2 seeing how it's going to be deprecated in a few months: https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 1):

In case, if someone is looking for an f string equivalent, use the following:

```
In [69]: arr = np.array([1.4556, 2.4, 3.3245])

# printing only 3 digits after the decimal point
In [70]: f'{" ".join(format(c, ".3f") for c in arr)}'
Out[70]: '1.456 2.400 3.325'
```

---

A diluted version of this code would be, [thanks to the suggestion by NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947229/writing-arrays-and-strings-to-file-using-operator/55947802?noredirect=1#comment98551039_55947802):

```
In [95]: print(("{: .3f}"*len(arr)).format(*arr))
 1.456 2.400 3.325
```

Comment: But this doesn't respect the float formatting the OP wants, how do we ensure that?

Comment: Great, I will upvote for the fix , but actually the OP wants variable formatting `4d %.6f %.6f %.6f`, how can we do that, make a format array ?

Comment: for python 3... similar to the f-string but sometimes shorter …. ("{: .3f}"*len(arr)).format(*arr) … yields ' 1.456 2.400 3.325'