# How to add dynamic curly braces {} in python's string.format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an list which contains multiple lists inside as columns. The problem is that the amount of columns isn't fixed, there could be one, two, or more columns.
 I want to be able to print the list like:

```
print('{}->dynamically add more to contain the variables'.format(columns_list[0] ->to however many there are]))
```

This is to be used in some sort of loop.

```
import csv

rows_amount = 0
columns_amount = 0
stop = 0
with open('./new/new-page-1-table-1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = list(csv.reader(csv_file))

    for row in reader:
        columns_amount = len(row)
        #In this case, the column_amount = 2
```

In this case above, the column amount is = 2 if I want to print it I will write explicitely

```
print ('{}, {}'.format(row[0], row[1]))
```

If I want this to run on multiple csv files, is there a way to dynamically print all the columns?

Is there a way this can happen?

Comment: What do you mean by columns? An example input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: will add more details

Comment: More details would be great, but maybe just `"->".join(columns)`?

Comment: Added more details. I'm not sure if join would be able to achieve this

Comment: Why *wouldn't* join be able to achieve this? This looks exactly like what `str.join` is for...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - How to format variable number of arguments into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391059/python-how-to-format-variable-number-of-arguments-into-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the string you want to format, if you just want to have your list entries separated, you can do

```
print(", ".join(columns_list))
```

Using `join()`, you'll get your desired outcome for any number of columns.
It has a good runtime behaviour and handles the trailing/leading separator.

If your formatting needs the formatstring - though the first option would usually be preferred, notably in terms of readability - you could handle it like this:

```
print(("{} is a column! " * len(columns_list)).format(*columns_list))
```

You could mix such a requirement and have it robust like

```
print(", ".join(["{:<10}".format(col) for col in columns_list]))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391059/python-how-to-format-variable-number-of-arguments-into-a-string